# Descending sort in jquery data table does not work properly

Tags: jquery, datatables, columnsorting

I have created a table using jQuery data table. In a specific column I have a range of numeric values from 32 to 1000 (which has no string value).

For this column, I used following options:

> { title: "Approx.count" ,"sType": "numeric"},

Ascending sort works fine started from 32, but descending sort did not work (it starts from 99 instead of 1000).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried,

```
{ title: "Approx.count" ,"sType": "num"},
```

or you should try `html-num` if you are using html with numbers.

If you are using datatable version 1.10+ use the following code for sorting numbers using the inbuilt code,

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    columnDefs: [
       { type: 'formatted-num', targets: 0 }
    ]
 });
```

If you are using older version of data table (i.e. version < 1.10) then include the [formatted-numbers.js](https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.11/sorting/formatted-numbers.js) and try the above code. More on [DataTable sorting](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/)

Comment: I am using jquery.dataTables.min.js version 1.10.11. It still doesn't work!